# Nsxml parser in iOS

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

I am new in I phone programming. From the web service call i got a response and from that I have to get the data. I have tried everything i could but was unable to do that..I need the (the two questions i.e  what was the name of your childhood best fr? and what is your place of birth?) value   inside the  tag  help plz..... Below is the xml response which i have to parse....

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns1:isForgotPasswordResponse xmlns:ns1="http://ws.esb.pmp2.ilantus.com/">
         <ns1:return>
            <ns2:attributes xsi:nil="true" xmlns:ns2="http://vo.common.pmp2.ilantus.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns2:editAllAttributesBean xsi:nil="true" xmlns:ns2="http://vo.common.pmp2.ilantus.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns2:loginBean xmlns:ns2="http://vo.common.pmp2.ilantus.com">
               <ns2:changePwdOnNextLogon>false</ns2:changePwdOnNextLogon>
               <ns2:host>localhost</ns2:host>
               <ns2:lock>false</ns2:lock>
               <ns2:loginId>pxpuser1002</ns2:loginId>
               <ns2:loginPassword>Passw0rd</ns2:loginPassword>
               <ns2:newPassword xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
               <ns2:oldPassword xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
               <ns2:role>Help Desk User Role</ns2:role>
               <ns2:seedvalue>5VIQPHRXOBTMGRID</ns2:seedvalue>
               <ns2:user xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            </ns2:loginBean>
            <ns2:policyBeans xsi:nil="true" xmlns:ns2="http://vo.common.pmp2.ilantus.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns2:profileBean xmlns:ns2="http://vo.common.pmp2.ilantus.com">
               <ns2:attributes xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
               <ns2:email>Not specified</ns2:email>
               <ns2:firstName xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
               <ns2:isRegistered xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
               <ns2:lastName xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
               <ns2:loginBean xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
               <ns2:username xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            </ns2:profileBean>
            <ns2:qnABeans xsi:nil="true" xmlns:ns2="http://vo.common.pmp2.ilantus.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns2:questions xmlns:ns2="http://vo.common.pmp2.ilantus.com">
               <ns2:Attribute>
                  <ns2:attributeName>question1</ns2:attributeName>
                  <ns2:category xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns2:editable xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns2:entity_name xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns2:label xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns2:operation xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns2:options xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns2:required xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns2:sequence>0</ns2:sequence>
                  <ns2:type xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns2:value>What was the name of your childhood best fr?</ns2:value>
               </ns2:Attribute>
               <ns2:Attribute>
                  <ns2:attributeName>question2</ns2:attributeName>
                  <ns2:category xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns2:editable xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns2:entity_name xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns2:label xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns2:operation xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns2:options xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns2:required xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns2:sequence>0</ns2:sequence>
                  <ns2:type xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns2:value>Which is your place of birth?</ns2:value>
               </ns2:Attribute>
            </ns2:questions>
            <ns2:reportBean xsi:nil="true" xmlns:ns2="http://vo.common.pmp2.ilantus.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <ns2:secondFactorBean xmlns:ns2="http://vo.common.pmp2.ilantus.com">
               <ns2:attributes>
                  <ns2:Attribute>
                     <ns2:attributeName>End User Role</ns2:attributeName>
                     <ns2:category xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                     <ns2:editable xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                     <ns2:entity_name xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                     <ns2:label xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                     <ns2:operation xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                     <ns2:options xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                     <ns2:required xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                     <ns2:sequence>0</ns2:sequence>
                     <ns2:type xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                     <ns2:value>Enabled</ns2:value>
                  </ns2:Attribute>
                  <ns2:Attribute>
                     <ns2:attributeName>Help Desk User Role</ns2:attributeName>
                     <ns2:category xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                     <ns2:editable xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                     <ns2:entity_name xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                     <ns2:label xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                     <ns2:operation xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                     <ns2:options xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                     <ns2:required xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                     <ns2:sequence>0</ns2:sequence>
                     <ns2:type xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                     <ns2:value>Enabled</ns2:value>
                  </ns2:Attribute>
                  <ns2:Attribute>
                     <ns2:attributeName>Administrator Role</ns2:attributeName>
                     <ns2:category xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                     <ns2:editable xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                     <ns2:entity_name xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                     <ns2:label xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                     <ns2:operation xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                     <ns2:options xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                     <ns2:required xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                     <ns2:sequence>0</ns2:sequence>
                     <ns2:type xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                     <ns2:value>Disabled</ns2:value>
                  </ns2:Attribute>
               </ns2:attributes>
               <ns2:emailTemplate>Dear {0}, 
 
Please find the back up code for your multi factor authentication. 
Back up code:{1} 
Please configure your code manually, if you delete your entry from Google authenticator accidentally. 
 
Thank you, 
TEAM PXP. 
 
 
N.B. Please do not reply to this mail, as it is not monitored.</ns2:emailTemplate>
               <ns2:secondFactor>true</ns2:secondFactor>
               <ns2:statusBean>
                  <ns2:errorCode xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns2:errorMessage xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                  <ns2:result>true</ns2:result>
               </ns2:statusBean>
            </ns2:secondFactorBean>
            <ns2:statusBean xmlns:ns2="http://vo.common.pmp2.ilantus.com">
               <ns2:errorCode>PXPERROR11033</ns2:errorCode>
               <ns2:errorMessage>Either challenge or response or both not found for the user.pxpuser1002</ns2:errorMessage>
               <ns2:result>true</ns2:result>
            </ns2:statusBean>
         </ns1:return>
      </ns1:isForgotPasswordResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: can you post some of your xml parser code for further help

Comment: @LochanaRagupathy : I have tried Nsxml Parser examples bt nothing happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableString *xmlString;

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)nameSpaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    xmlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];    
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [xmlString appendString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{    
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ns2:value"])
    {
        if (![xmlString isEqual:@""])
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",xmlString);
            [SomeArray addObject:xmlString];
        }
    }

    //Release string
    [xmlString release];
    xmlString = nil;
}
```

Here `NSMutableString` is a variable that keeps track of the current element in `foundCharacters` method, and append the string and on `didEndElement` method using elementName we can recognize value for that tag.

**UPDATE**

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    //update your UI here after parsing is finished
}
```

Comment: Where should I initialise the array somearray

Comment: someArray is just holder of values retrieved from xml. So just initialize it before parsing xml.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. but i need a liitle help from you.. Please tell me exactly where to initialise the array and exactly where  should i retrieve the data from the array .. because i just need the two questions

Comment: declare array globally and initialize it before your code for parsing xml.

Comment: Tell me in which place i should retrieve the data from array and how?

Comment: you should do that on your web service response

Comment: M sorry i didn't get u... actually i need to read the first two values from the array someArray. so where should i do it? in the didendelement method. or somewhere else?

Comment: for(NSMutableString * str in array)
            {
                NSLog(str);
            }

Comment: its very lengthy.. can't paste it here. where can i giv you the values ?

Comment: If you want to access first two value of array use it like [array objectAtIndex:0];  [array objectAtIndex:1];

Comment: Thanks Bhargavi .. but my question is that in which place of my code should i do that?

Comment: Once you done parsing your xml and array is ready to use at that time you can get values.

Comment: How can i display the  values of the array on the screen..?  i am using didEndDocument method and inside that i am adding output.text=[array onjectAtindex:0]; but nothing is happening

Comment: See update on answer . Use parserDidEndDocument method after parsing is finished, update UI

Comment: Thanks.. Bhargavi i will be facing a lot of problem in the near future.. will u help me plz?

Comment: I also need the value of <ns2:result> and <ns2:errorMessage>  inside the <ns2:statusBean>..  can u help?

Comment: You can differentiate values using if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ns2:value"]) condition